# Console has "Cannot read property "top" of undefined error"

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap affix on my navbar to get it fixed on top, once it's been reached by scrolling down.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container"><!--container-->
        <div class="row" id="navigation"><!--header-->
            <div class="col-md-12"><!--col-md-12-->
                <div class="navbar" id="nav"><!--nav-->
                    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/about-efti/">About EFTI</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/our-coaches/">Our Coaches</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/efti-forum/">EFTI Forum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://endurancefilmsti.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>               
                    </div>       
                </div><!--nav-->
            </div><!--col-md-12-->
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div><!--header-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div>
```

[image: This is what my console looks like]

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });
});
```

I have set the position for the nav in my CSS, as required by Bootstrap documentation.

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: It means that the call to `.offset()` is returning `undefined`. That, in turn, means that there's no element found with the id "navigation".

Comment: I changed the id in the selector to #nav, and it I still get the same error. And I definitely have the #nav in my CSS style.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in your CSS - what matters is whether there's an element with that id in your HTML. (However I see that it's apparently there in the HTML you posted.) Is it possible that the JavaScript code runs before that part of the page is created?

Comment: If it's in my CSS, then it's in my HTML too, that was my point. JS is at the bottom of the page, JQuery.js and bootstrap.min.js are as well. One thing I could do is wrap it in a ready handler.

Comment: Well you can add code to test: `console.log("nav: " + $("#nav").length);` - if that prints "nav: 1" then it's on the page, but if it prints "nav: 0" then it is not.

Comment: It printed 1, now what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64028/discussion-between-nosille-and-pointy).

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap has a class `.navbar-fixed-top` which you could apply to your div with the class `.navbar`.

I would imagine that would do the trick for you.

Comment: .navbar-fixed-top will fix it to the top at all times. What I want is something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/Uaa3U/. I want it to fix at the top ONCE it's been reached, not by default.